# NullPointerException when supplier returns null in Spring Cloud Stream 3.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I'm getting a NullPointerException when a Supplier returns null using Spring Cloud Stream v3.1.3. Here's the code:

```
package com.example.loggingconsumer;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LoggingConsumerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoggingConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Supplier<Person> generate() {
        return () -> {
            return null;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<Person, Person> capitalize() {
        return person -> {
            if (person != null) {
                person.setName(person.getName().toUpperCase());
                System.out.println(person.getName());
            }
            return person;
        };
    }

 public static class Person {
            private String name;
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }
            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }
            public String toString() {
                return this.name;
            }
        }
    }
```

application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.function.definition=generate|capitalize
```

I check for null in the capitalize function, so why do I get this error every second (every poll). If I remove capitalize, no error. If I return a non-null person object, no error.

```
2021-06-13 15:15:47.686 ERROR 57019 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:427)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:348)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$5(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:341)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.convertNonMessageInputIfNecessary(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:1078)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.convertInputIfNecessary(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:949)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:634)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.lambda$andThen$0(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:561)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:637)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.apply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:489)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.get(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:500)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.get(PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.java:83)
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows$1.doReceive(IntegrationFlows.java:167)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:444)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:413)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Sure we can fix the NPE in favor of some other exception or simply ignore the event all together, but regardless we do NOT allow messages with null payloads so returning null from the Supplier

Comment: Some kind of info/debug log would be fine. My supplier polls a kafka broker, so if the broker is empty (which it will be a lot), there will be a null payload.

Comment: Is there a way to catch this exception (some kind of override) and I can do it myself.

Comment: Debug log would be more in line with 1.x versions I think.

Comment: Then you can use your own poller in combination with StreamBridge and only send messages when you have something